# What is a part site in eclipse terms?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, concept

What is an eclipse part site?...
I have searched for this concept in particular but found nothing. Anybody know a site (:D) where i can get some info on this concept ?

LE here's an example
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIViewSite.html
"implemention of view part sites"...it is also mentioned in some tutorials but not explained

Comment: It's not anything. Post a link to a reference if you want to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A part site is basically just a thing that holds a view or an editor in the Eclipse workbench.  You can get a reference to a view's or editor's part site by calling `IViewPart.getViewSite()` or `IEditorPart.getEditorSite()`.

Here is the documentation for the returned interface: [IWorkbenchPartSite](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIWorkbenchPartSite.html)

Comment: That interface, IWorkbenchPartSite, if I'm not mistaken, is actually for "workbench part sites" - and the question asked specifically about "view part sites" in the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the API documentation that you linked, a "view part site" is simply an instance of a IViewPart.  Notice that there are comments such as "The workbench exposes its implemention of view part sites via this interface", "Returns the action bars for this part site" and "Returns the secondary id for this part site's part".

Because it's an interface, and Eclipse doesn't want you attempting to implement it, you should simply get these "view part sites" via IViewPart.getViewSite(), and then you can use it via the methods provided on the interface's [use page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/advanced/help.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/class-use/IViewSite.html).

Comment: As far as I understand, an `IViewPart` is just a "view part". "View part site" is an `IViewSite`, so @Mike Daniels' answer is closer to truth.